# How to create a custom view to create below UI in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, view

[image]

I can create this by using XML. But here my requirement is if I set attribute show_stepCount=3, then 3 views should be drawn on the canvas. I should be able to select one item at a time. I am not able to understand should I inherit my custom class by View or with some other view type to achieve the below UI.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you correctly, but if you mean that the number of items on the `View` itself is variable, then you could do that relatively easily by subclassing `TabLayout`.

Comment: @MikeM Thank you for the prompt response, but here I don't want to use Viewpager2.

Comment: Huh? I didn't say `ViewPager2`. I said `TabLayout`.

Comment: Super quick example I threw together from a custom tab `View` I just happened to have done for another question yesterday: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11HAG1536jcpJkAf5PLSRvRRvJR04Dyz5/view?usp=sharing. Looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vkYb.png.

Comment: I know it's been a while, and that you surely already have something working, but I recently realized that [`MaterialButtonToggleGroup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButtonToggleGroup) ([material.io docs](https://m2.material.io/components/buttons/android#toggle-button)) might also be a good fit for this, depending on exactly what behavior and look is needed. Using `MaterialButton`s, it'll automatically round the corners on the ends, and since it's just `Button`s, you can use compound drawables for the icons. Thought I'd mention it. Cheers!